# Recreate image with ffmpeg safe?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I want to use `ffmpeg` to recreate an image file that is uploaded. I know that in PHP you can use `imagecreatefromjpeg`, `imagecreatefrompng` and `imagejpeg` etc. to recreate images. That way, if there is any hidden malware in the original images, it will 'break' / be mangled.

But I want to use this ffmpeg command to recreate image files:
`ffmpeg -i in.jpg out.jpg`
I have tested converting an image file that has PHP code stored in its EXIF field, and after converting it, the PHP code is no longer executed in the converted file..

Also, the converted file is smaller in size: from 45.9 KB to 11 KB..

Is that a safe way?

**EDIT**
Btw, I am also checking the MIME type etc, but MIME can be forged, hence recreating image files is recommended.. I want to convert files on another server where there is no PHP installed. That way I can also avoid any potential PHP memory issues.

Comment: **Why** do you want to use `ffmpeg` for this? I would suspect the file is smaller due to a lower default quality setting.

Comment: Yes, the quality goes down to 79, and there is less meta data in the converted file. I want to convert it on another server where there is no PHP installed. That way i can also avoid any potential memory issues with PHP.

Comment: If you just want to strip exif data you can use `exiftool`. If you want to re-encode for whatever reason the perceived safety of ffmpeg may be subjective, however it is continuously tested by oss-fuzz and also Coverity Scan if that makes a difference to you. So use a recent build from the git master branch to take advantage of the commits due to the fuzzing, etc.

Comment: My issue is with the ability of someone hiding some kind of C or PHP code in a file that has a JPEG as MIME type. I hope `ffmpeg` can break that during converting.. Also, the files are not stored inside the web root.